# How many times is a local variable created when instantiating a function object? ( advanced )

Tags: javascript

In the message object below, if I call it like this:

```
var message_object = new Message( response_element );
message_object.display( 'empty' );
```

is the messages array created for each call to new Message()...if so how can I ensure there is only one messages array, as that is all I need?

```
var Message = function( element )
{
    var messages =  
    {
        name:         'Please enter a valid name',
        email:        'Please enter a valid email',
        pass:         'Please enter passoword, 6-40 characters',
        url:          'Please enter a valid url',
        title:        'Please enter a valid title',
        tweet:        'Please enter a valid tweet',
        empty:        'Please complete all fields',
        email_s:      'Please enter a valid email.',
        same:         'Please make emails equal',
        taken:        'Sorry, that email is taken',
        validate:     'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:chris@domain.com">support</a> to reset your password',
    }
    this.display = function( type ) 
    {
        element.innerHTML = messages[ type ];
        new Effects().fade( element, 'down', 4000 );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that entire function would be executed each time, and the messages object AND the function would be redefined each time.

What you probably want to do is wrap it in a closure, and make use of Javascript's prototypical inheritance

```
var Message = (function () {
    var messages = {
        name:         'Please enter a valid name',
        email:        'Please enter a valid email',
        pass:         'Please enter passoword, 6-40 characters',
        url:          'Please enter a valid url',
        title:        'Please enter a valid title',
        tweet:        'Please enter a valid tweet',
        empty:        'Please complete all fields',
        email_s:      'Please enter a valid email.',
        same:         'Please make emails equal',
        taken:        'Sorry, that email is taken',
        validate:     'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:chris@host.com">support</a> to reset your password',
    };
    var Message = function (element) {
        this.element = element;
    };

    Message.prototype.display = function( type ) {
        this.element.innerHTML = messages[ type ];
        new Effects().fade( this.element, 'down', 4000 );
    };
    return Message;
}());
```

This keeps the `messages` object private to the 'class'.

Comment: Doesn't this create a singleton instance of an anonymous object?  How would you create another instance?  Thx.

Comment: @Madbreaks - it returns a function that is then used as a constructor with `new Message()` the same as the `new Message()` syntax from the question.

Comment: @Madbreaks, this is sometimes called an IIFE: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Is this the constructor? -> var Message = function () {};

Comment: I'm trying to build professional JavaScript, should I update to this method or is it over-kill on something like this?

Comment: @TheAllFoo yes, that's right. The constructor is created inside the closure and returned to be assigned to `Message`. Wrapping private variables in a closure is a good practice, in my opinion, and I wouldn't consider this overkill. It really helps in the future if you need to refactor your code. Since you are 100% guaranteed that no outside code is using these variables, it makes it much easier and safer to change.

Comment: ...cool..thanks a bunch..this clears up alot as I already know how to do these things in PHP, C++, etc...now I kind of get the JS way...thanks again.

Comment: If you wanted to explore this further, you could look at using the AMD style (asynchronous module definition). Each 'module' of code is defined inside its own wrapper to avoid conflicts and polluting the global space. Accessing modules defined in other files is done via specifically requiring just the modules you need. This helps even further with code maintenance and refactoring.

Comment: ...when the .js is loaded, this "object" self executes...this takes a bit of run-time correct?..not that it is alot but relative to the simpler method with out the self-execution?

Comment: correct. If you were concerned about that (you shouldn't be), you could do some 'lazy loading'. Declare `messages` in the same place in the closure, but don't define the object there. Inside of the constructor or in the `display` method, write an `if`: `if (!messages) { messages = { .... }; }`. It'll still only be defined once, only when you need it, but it will be checked each time the function is run. Useful if you really do have a large amount of data, or it is complicated to define the data, or if you do not expect the data to actually be needed in most cases.

Comment: good explanation of lazy loading...I use this in PHP but it does it in code I haven't looked at yet.

Answer (score 1):

`messages` is an object not an array, but yes: a new one is created on every call to your `Message()` function.

If you only need the one copy, what would be a "static" variable in other languages, one way is to do the following:

```
var Message = function( element )
{
    this.display = function( type ) 
    {
        element.innerHTML = this.messages[ type ];
        new Effects().fade( element, 'down', 4000 );
    }
};

Message.prototype.messages = {
    name:         'Please enter a valid name',
    email:        'Please enter a valid email',
    pass:         'Please enter passoword, 6-40 characters',
    url:          'Please enter a valid url',
    title:        'Please enter a valid title',
    tweet:        'Please enter a valid tweet',
    empty:        'Please complete all fields',
    email_s:      'Please enter a valid email.',
    same:         'Please make emails equal',
    taken:        'Sorry, that email is taken',
    validate:     'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:chris@host.com">support</a> to reset your password',
};
```

Properties and methods added to the `prototype` can be accessed by all instances - note that within the `display()` method it is accessed as `this.messages`.

(Note that it may be sensible to define your `display()` method on the prototype too, which would involve making an instance copy of the `element` parameter with `this.element = element;`.)

Comment: this realy bothers me that I have to take it out of the "enclosure".  Is there another way?  Also, are they now accessible outside of Message..i.e. no longer private?

Comment: You are correct that it is no longer private. If you want private variables use the method that nickf showed.

Comment: I ended up using this for now...until I fully understand the the module pattern and how it uses memory and processor.  My guess is that this is why JavaScript is not considered a "strong" OO language...just to get static based components you have to use prototypical inheritance...relative to compiled languages...static is hard to do in JavaScript....if you want static private....then you  have to get even more complicated and use self-executing functions...